# p5.js && ecmascript6 notation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, p5.js

I want use `p5.js` function inside a class with ECMAScript notation.

How to fix this code?

```
class Sketch {
    constructor(p, params) {
        // generate vars use in class with object
        if (typeof params !== 'undefined') {
            for (let key in params) this[key] = params[key];
        }
        // p5.js object
        this.p = p;
    }
    // p5.js setup method
    setup() {
        this.p.createCanvas();
    }
    // p5.js draw method
    draw() {
    }
}
sketch = new Sketch(p5,{});
```

Error:

> this.p.createCanvas is not a function

Comment: What is wrong with this code? I don't see what you would want to fix.

Comment: this.p.createCanvas is not a function

Comment: How are you calling `setup`?

Comment: i called to the setup by this : sketch.setup()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The docs](http://p5js.org/examples/instance-mode-instantiation.html) say that you must *instantiate* `p5` and pass your initialiser function that creates the method on `p`:

```
const myp5 = new p5(p => {
    p.setup = () => {
        p.createCanvas();
    };
    …
});
```

See also the [Global and instance mode](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) tutorial.

This is a really weird construction however. Although it's not documented, in ES6 it should be possible to subclass `p5`:

```
class Sketch extends p5 {
    constructor(params) {
        super(p => {
            // do any setup in here that needs to happen before the sketch starts
            // (e.g. create event handlers)
            // `p` refers to the instance that becomes `this` after the super() call
            // so for example
            if (typeof params == 'object' && params != null)
                for (let key in params)
                    p[key] = params[key];
        });

        // `this` itself is the p5.js object
    }
    // p5.js setup method
    setup() {
        this.createCanvas();
    }
    // p5.js draw method
    draw() {
    }
}
const myp5 = new Sketch({});
```

Notice that the `p5` constructor will invoke your methods; you don't have to do `myp5.setup()` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Tinkering with this issue. I was able to implement inheritance of p5 kinda like so:

```js
import p5 from 'p5';

const MIN_RAD = 150;
const MAX_RAD = 250;
const ITEM_COLOR = 'red';
const BG = 'rgba(50,50,50,.05)';
const VELOCITY = 1;

export default class Sketch extends p5 {

    constructor(sketch = ()=>{}, node = false, sync = false) {
        super(sketch, node, sync);
        console.log('Sketch [this:%o]', this);

        this.setup = this.setup.bind(this);
        this.draw = this.draw.bind(this);
        this.render = this.render.bind(this);
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
        this.windowResized = this.windowResized.bind(this);
    }

    setup() {
        console.log('setup', this.windowWidth, this.windowHeight);
        this.createCanvas(this.windowWidth, this.windowHeight, p5.WEBGL);

        this.bg = this.color(BG);
        this.itemColor = this.color(ITEM_COLOR);
        this.rad = MIN_RAD;
        this.grow = true;
        this.frame = 0;
    }

    draw() {
        this.increment();
        this.render();
    }

    render() {
        let x = this.windowWidth / 2;
        let y = this.windowHeight / 2;

        this.background(this.bg);
        this.fill(this.itemColor);
        this.stroke(this.itemColor);
        this.ellipse(x, y, this.rad, this.rad);
    }

    increment() {
        this.rad = this.grow ? this.rad + VELOCITY : this.rad - VELOCITY;

        if (this.rad > MAX_RAD) {
            this.grow = false;
        };

        if (this.rad < MIN_RAD) {
            this.grow = true;
        }

        this.frame++;
    }

    // EVENTS

    windowResized() {
        console.log('windowResized', this.windowWidth, this.windowHeight);
        this.resizeCanvas(this.windowWidth, this.windowHeight);
    }
}
```

This class can be imported normally, and instantiated by invoking the constructor.

```
import Sketch from './sketch';
...
const sketch = new Sketch();
```

Digging through the source code a little, there are two critical states that auto-magically activate the so-called 'global' mode, where p5 dumps its guts onto `window` (to be avoided).

- 1) at [init.js#L21](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/init.js#L21), if `draw` and `setup` both exist on the `window`
- 2) on [core.js#L496](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/core.js#L496), if the `sketch` argument is falsey

`p5/Core` uses these conditions to set its internal `_isGlobal` prop which is used to define context as either `window` or `this`, and conditionally acts on this throughout. EG:[core.js#L271](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/master/src/core/core.js#L271)

Just expanding on the selected answer (which is correct, except I get errors passing in an empty object).

Frankly, both of the documented construction methods are unsatisfactory. This is an improvement, but we still have to do extra work to manage scope.

Comment: Is binding all the methods really necessary?

Comment: Seems to be. Tried a bunch of different configurations and I get scoping issues if they're not bound. P5s handling of context is funky to say the least.