# How can I include a Javascript library with a namespace without manually exporting every function?

Tags: javascript, namespaces

So my problem is I am including two Javascript libraries which both register lots of variables to the global namespace (Specifically, [mlweb](https://mlweb.loria.fr/) and [p5.js](https://p5js.org/)). They are both extensive libraries, and share a lot of function and variable names. However, I'm also using Tensorflow.js, which doesn't conflict at all since all its functions require its namespace (`tf.tensor`, `tf.Model()`) to call them.

I know I can manually export all the functions in those two libraries, but it's a lot of manual work. Is there a way to import the other libraries that forces them into a namespace without my having to write out every function? Specifically, I would like a way to include a library such that it registers every variable and function as a property of the library name like in Python, a javascript equivalent of

```
import cv2
cv2.imread("foo.bar")
```

Comment: No, there's nothing you can do about scripts that behave badly and put everything in the global scope. ES6 modules solve this, but not everyone uses these yet. Find a library that is packaged as a module.

Comment: That said, unlike ml.js, the p5.js library appears to support ES6, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50536543/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43079407/1048572)